# How to get data from a variable parameter list?

Tags: c++, c

I have following function with only a variable parameter list (**Without supporting/fixed  argument**). Is it possible to get values passed to this function? I am using ANSI format.

```
Foo( ... )
{
}
```

Adding some more points for clarity. In my special case, the number of arguments and their types are stored in a .xml file as configurations which can be accessed from Foo().

**Edit:**

I am adding some information from my trial and error. I partially succeeded to get data from list as follows.

```
va_list Arguments;

Arguments = (( va_list ) &Arguments + Offset );

Data = va_arg( Arguments, Type );
```

Idea I put behind this is directly reading data from stack. Here the problem factor is *Offset* whose value is varying according to the number of arguments I am passing into Foo(). For example, when I am passing a pointer only, I put its value as 16 to get correct result. I found this values with trial and error. I want to derive *Offset* from parameter list that my program can run without any runtime failure in all possible cases. Can someone tell me the relation between this *Offset* and the parameter list.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for developing this.

Answer (score 2):

Variadic functions with no fixed arguments are not supported in modern C.  However, for backwards compatibility purposes, they are supported by [varargs.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h#varargs.h).  See also [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg), which provides the following example code.  Note the K&R-style function definition required by varargs.

```
#include <varargs.h>
void foo(va_alist) va_dcl {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap);
    while(...) {
        ...
        x = va_arg(ap, type);
        ...
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variadic functions require fixed arguments in modern C because functions should be able to sort out what to do from the arguments. For instance, `printf()` knows what arguments to retrieve from the stack based on the format string. If you omit these fixed parameters, there is no checking on the correctness of the arguments.

If `Foo()` performs a lookup of some kind, then it would make sense to pass either xml reference or the values to look up as a parameter (or better: both).

Going back to K&R style C is quite nasty. Possibly you can change the splitting between parser and interpreter `Foo()` to use a more clear interface.

Comment: Thanks; Actually I am not in search of something to pass because I should pass something. I am trying to solve it without adding any redundancy or dummy information.

Comment: If your function needs some global data (like a xml reference) then it would make sense to me to use this (this would not be redundant, but improve (lower) coupling within your program.